# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'

Tags: python, django

I'm working with django 1.7 and i have created this management command:

File structure:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    management/
               __init__.py
               commands/
                        __init__.py
                        modal_asign.py
```

Code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from webinar.models import Webinar

class Commands(BaseCommand):

    help = 'Assign modal link to every webinar'

    def handle(self):
        latest_webinar = Webinar.objects.all().order_by('-webinar_date')[0]
        for webinars in latest_webinar:
            print "http://webinar.academiaa2.com/webinars/#displayModal" + webinars
```

and i'm getting this error when trying to test it with `python manage.py modal_asign`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/rafael/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/rafael/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/rafael/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 238, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/rafael/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 42, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class name is called `Commands`, whereas django expects it to be called `Command`. Hence the error.

Change

```
class Commands(BaseCommand):
```

to

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
```